# Prevent Ctrl+Mouse Wheel default behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firefox

In my application I have places where custom zooming and custom scrolling are binded to the Ctrl+mouse wheel and Shift+mouse wheel respectively. The code looks like this:

```
private mousewheelCallback = (event: MouseWheelEvent) => {
    if(event.ctrlKey == true) {
        if(event.deltaY > 0) {
            this.zoomOut();
        }
        else {
            this.zoomIn();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(event.deltaMode == event.DOM_DELTA_PIXEL) {
            if(event.shiftKey == true){
                this.scrollbarX.nativeElement.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                this.scrollbarY.nativeElement.scrollTop += event.deltaY;
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This works like a charm under Chrome, but Firefox doesn't want to honor the event handler even though it returns false and also calls `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but try it by using `event.stopPropagation();`.
For more information refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault